# SO(3) invariant metric on two sphere

Tags: group-theory

I read that the $SO(3)$ invariant metric on the two sphere $S_2$ is given by

$ds^2=d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$

How can I derive this? and how does $g_{ij}$ look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2-sphere can be parameterized by
$$\begin{cases}
x = \sin\theta \cos\phi \\
y = \sin\theta \sin\phi \\
z = \cos\theta
\end{cases}$$
where $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi.$

From this we get
$$\begin{cases}
dx = \cos\theta\,d\theta \cos\phi - \sin\theta \sin\phi\,d\phi \\
dy = \cos\theta\,d\theta \sin\phi + \sin\theta \cos\phi\,d\phi \\
dz = -\sin\theta\,d\theta
\end{cases}$$
so the ordinary $SO(3)$-invariant metric is given by
$$
ds^2
= dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2
\\= (\cos\theta\,d\theta \cos\phi - \sin\theta \sin\phi\,d\phi)^2
+ (\cos\theta\,d\theta \sin\phi + \sin\theta \cos\phi\,d\phi)^2
+ (-\sin\theta\,d\theta)^2
\\= d\theta^2 + \sin^2\phi\,d\phi^2
.
$$

In the coordinate system $(\theta,\phi)$ we therefore have
$$\begin{array}{ll}
g_{\theta\theta} = 1 & g_{\theta\phi} = 0 \\
g_{\phi\theta} = 0 & g_{\phi\phi} = \sin^2\phi
\end{array}$$